# How to get a database file from apk file?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, apk

I have an **android application apk file**. I want to open a database file from apk file: is there any official tool to open a database file from **apk file**?

By using extractor I extract that apk file. Finally I get some files namely `assets`, `bin`, `lib`, `res` folder, but I cant find the database file and layout files.

I searched the path given below:

> assets->data

but I didn't found that ***data folder*** inside the ***assets folder***. Why?

Comment: Probably the db isn't there. Most probably it's generated in the app and then filled. Or it's downloaded. You should look for it in some other folder on your sd card, maybe...

Comment: no no i am asking that, for example we are using wts up,we chat or anything. then we extracting we cant get a database file???

Comment: WhatsApp generates its database itself, as most apps do. In this case, it's also encrypted, for privacy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Database that is actually used is not stored in the APK. It needs to be in a writable location. Canonically it's in `databases` under the application's data directory e.g. `/data/data/package.name/databases`.

Many apps generate their databases dynamically in code. Some apps ship with a pre-populated database in assets, but even they need to copy it to a writable location before using.

Comment: for example we are using wts up,we chat or anything. then we extracting we cant get a database file???

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be reading other apps' databases. There are OS level protections to prevent you from doing so - you need root or a poorly implemented app with too permissive database file mode. Also, reverse engineering apps is somewhat borderline off-topic on Stack Overflow - we're more interested in building new apps instead of reversing existing ones here.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases developer might have loaded data from ms excel sheet/textfile/sqllite. so if that's the cases, the files will be under
res/raw folder